# MPLAB X IDE (NetBeans) cannot find header file in same directory as source (macOS case-sensitive filesystem)

Tags: netbeans

I've just started using the MPLAB X IDE and opened a noddy sample project provided by a colleague.  There's 2 files in it - Example.c and Config.h - both in the top-level Project.X directory.  But when I open Example.c I get warning squiggles that Config.h cannot be found, despite the #include using double-quote, meaning "look in the source file directory first".  As it is, the warning message just talks about the system include path.

HOWEVER ... I'm running the IDE on a Mac with the Project.X directory stored on a disk configured as APFS Case-sensitive (which is where I do all my Linux-based dev work, for obvious reasons), and if I move the directory to my home folder (which is on a normal APFS non-case-sensitive volume) then the IDE successfully finds the file.

So I guess the real problem is that MPLAB X / NetBeans does weird and inappropriate case-folding on a Mac when the underlying filesystem is case-sensitive.  How do I fix it (other than by using a case-insensitive filesystem, because that isn't really an option).

[image: Unresolved include directive warning]